# How do I paginate an array of _id in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

Currently, I have this confusion which is to paginate an array of items in a Schema.

So technically, every user has a cart and I want to paginate the cart's items. For example let say the cart has 18 items stored. I want to paginate the cart to only 5 items.

**Here's the schema**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true},
  cart: [{
     type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'
  }],
});
```

**Here's the route**

My current Approach

```
router.get('/cart', (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id })
    .populate({
    path: 'cart',
    options: { limit: 5 }
  })
  .exec((err, user) => {

    res.render('order/cart', { user: user });
  });
});
```

My current approach will definitely limit the items shown from 18 items to only 5 items, but this creates a new problem which now I can't calculate the total price of the cart because it only limit to 5 items per request.

[image]

Comment: With [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/). `.select({ 'cart': { '$slice': [skip,limit] } })`. It's been around since the first release of MongoDB exactly for that purpose.

Comment: Strange that the question is marked as duplicate. Mongoose != MongoDB, and the question stated as duplicate is about MongoDB and doesn't answer this one. @NeilLunn 's comment is the real answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the pagination on the client side, this way you'll get all the products from the server, but display only five on the client.
It will allow you calculate the average or other calculation on all the data. also it will allow you filtering and sorting all the data.

If you have a large amount of data, it will take long time for the first time for the client to load the data from the server, so for large amount of data it may be not the right way to go, in this case you probably want to load the data in chuncks, and maybe in the background, and 
perform the calculation using the server maybe also in the background -for optimization.

You can find pros and cons of server/client pagentaion https://dzone.com/articles/pagination-server-side-or-clie